# What is the difference (if any) between "defined" and "well-defined"?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, terminology

Recently I've seen this comment w.r.t. behavior (emphasis added):

> Generally, it's not undefined, but **not entirely well-defined either**.

It confused me a bit, because if the behavior is not undefined, then it is defined. Hence, what is the difference (if any) between *defined behavior* and *well-defined behavior*?

Note that the standard has no term *well-defined behavior*. However, it has term *well-defined semantics*. So, the question can be similar: what is the difference (if any) between *defined semantics* and *well-defined semantics*?

In general: what is the difference (if any) between *defined* and *well-defined*?

Reason of the question: better understanding of the standard.

Comment: First time seeing the `language-lawyer` tag. You should include what behavior this is mentioning.

Comment: “Well defined” is not a formal term. If something is fully and clearly defined, it is well defined. In contrast, a behavior may be defined but in ways that are incomplete, such as leaving some choice to an implementation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Re: "leaving some choice to an implementation": if the IB is required to be documented, then such behavior is still "fully and clearly defined" (by implementation). Or do I miss something? Perhaps the unspecified behavior is an example of "defined but in ways that are incomplete"?

Comment: @pmor: If something is required to be documented by the implementation, and the implementation conforms, then it is fully and clearly defined within that implementation. But it is not fully defined for C generally.

Comment: Moreso that the definition of what it _should_ do is there, but there may be different ways of achieving it (think how different compilers can implement functionality in different ways)

Comment: Candidate example of _not entirely well-defined_: How many significant digits are examined in converting a string to a `double`? Consider the exact text value of `DBL_TRUE_MIN/2` is hundreds of significant digits. Changing the least digit up/down, the best conversion value is `DBL_TRUE_MIN` or `0.0`. It is common that `strtod()` does not consider the hundreds of significant digits, but only a truncated about (e.g. maybe 20), thus returning the same value even when a great `strtod()` would differentiate. AFAIK, C does not require _defining_ this level of detail - so not _entirely well-defined_.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What if IB says "the behavior is as per hardware" and the hardware user manual says "If *some_condition* then the results are undefined"? In this case 1) the behavior is defined by implementation (i.e. by hardware), and 2) the implementation (i.e. hardware) does not define the behavior for some cases. In this case the IB does not define the behavior for all the cases. Hence, this is not IB, because it is not implementation-_defined_ behavior (for all the cases). Any thoughts / ideas / comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well-defined is what we usually call code containing neither undefined, unspecified or implementation-defined behavior. The definition of a strictly conforming program from chapter 4 might be helpful:

> *A strictly conforming program* shall use only those features of the language and library specified in this International Standard. It shall not produce output dependent on any unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior, and shall not exceed any minimum implementation limit.

Any snippet of C code fulfilling the above could informally said to be well-defined, as in defined by the ISO C language standard and portable. As opposed to for example *implementation-defined* meaning documented compiler-specific behavior.